# Ruby on Rails themoviedb-api gem isn't recognized by app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm crating movie/series focused app and I decided to use this gem: https://github.com/18Months/themoviedb-api#configuration. I added it to my Gemfile, then I used 'bundle install' command, the gem was successfully installed. So far I have done everything by the book. After installation I tried to check if it works properly so I insert this code into one of my controllers' index actions:

```
  def index
    @series = Series.all
    Tmdb::Api.key("my_api_key")
    Tmdb::Movie.detail(550, language: 'it')
  end
```

Unfortunately my app doesn't seem to recognize Tmdb api, and I am getting the error: 
uninitialized constant SeriesController::Tmdb

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: the configuration files says that you need to include that in an initializer

Comment: Restarting server worked, @FabrizioBertoglio what do you mean by initializer, is it setup.rb file?

Comment: @Mark nice. Read the guide, it says to set up an initializer inside `config/initializers` read more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files